# How do I make rows of data become grouped columns?

Tags: sql-server

I want to group by ID but have each column group show up as a new horizontal set of columns.

I have a table with data like this

```
╔════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ Phone ║  Type  ║
╠════╬═══════╬════════╣
║  A ║   111 ║ home   ║
║  A ║   222 ║ work   ║
║  B ║   333 ║ cell   ║
║  B ║   444 ║ school ║
╚════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

I want it to look like

```
╔════╦════════╦═══════╦════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ Phone1 ║ Type1 ║ Phone2 ║ Type2  ║
╠════╬════════╬═══════╬════════╬════════╣
║  A ║    111 ║ home  ║    222 ║ work   ║
║  B ║    333 ║ cell  ║    444 ║ school ║
╚════╩════════╩═══════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Ideally I would find a solution that would handle an arbitrary number of repeating groups but I could hard code the number if I had to.

I could have up to 100,000 unique IDs with 20 repeating sets of column groups each with up to 5 individual columns.

It seems like PIVOT would help with this but I can't figure out how.

EDIT: To be very clear here I do not want the row data to become column headers.  I want the current column headers to repeat and have the row data span out into horizontal groups.  There is no summation or aggregation here.  This is why PIVOT doesn't seem to work (unless I am missing something which I hope I am!)

SQL Server 2012

Comment: I'm not sure if pivot could help because I suppose you have an unknown number of types.

Comment: @xpy: for an unknown number of types it's possible to use dynamic sql for the pivot....

Comment: This has been answered hundreds of times around here and all over the internet. Just search for "dynamic pivot" or "dynamic crosstab". Here is a link to my favorite methodology and article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: @SeanLange The problem with PIVOT that I have not seen answered (and believe me I searched!) is that I don't just want the values of the rows to become the columns.  If you look at the question I want the column names to repeat in groups with the same data still in the rows, just grouped.

Comment: Yeah I see that. Then you REALLY need to look at the article I posted. One of the benefits of using a dynamic cross tab is you have this flexibility, which you don't get with a dynamic pivot.

Comment: @SeanLange It's really the repeating of groups of columns that is the hard part here.  None of these examples show a repetition of columns in a series, they just show transformation from rows to columns which is not what I am doing here.

Comment: If you read and understand how a dynamic crosstab works it is actually quite simple to extend it to groups like this. Read that article and take it all in. It is not a simple concept and takes a bit to fully understand it. Then try just doing a single "group". Once you get it you will see how easy it is to extend it.

Comment: @SeanLange If you have an example that does not do summations and repeats groups of columns without changing the data I would appreciate that.  The article does a good job of explaining how to create dynamic groups of summarized data but that is not what I am doing here.

Comment: Yeah until you use it a time or two it is kind of hard to make the mental leap that you can use MAX as an aggregate. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, I know that trick, but what am I aggregating on?  There is no reference for "this is the 3rd set of columns from this particular ID".  Max (or Min) will just get you one value per group but I want the first value + the second value + the third value etc.  Repeating the horizontal groups is the hard part, not getting the values in the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a dynamic crosstab as suggested by the article by Jeff Moden at sql server central.

His article can be found here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    ID char(1)
    , Phone int
    , MyType varchar(10)
)

insert #Something
select 'A', 111, 'home' union all
select 'A', 222, 'work' union all
select 'B', 333, 'cell' union all
select 'B', 444, 'school'

select *
from #Something

declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 
'with OrderedResults as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by phone) as RowNum
    from #Something
)
select ID';

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = ' from OrderedResults Group by ID order by ID';


with E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
)

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion + 
    ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then Phone end) as Phone' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) +
    ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then MyType end) as Type' + CAST(N as varchar(6))

from cteTally t
where t.N <= 
(
    select top 1 Count(*)
    from #Something
    group by ID
    order by COUNT(*) desc
)

select @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion

declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion;
exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute
```

Comment: I stand corrected, this solved the problem!  I have some work to do to get it to fit my tables but I used it on a simple table and it correctly repeated the column groups.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad that worked for you. The real trick there is using the tally table as the base for aggregation.

Comment: Oh and make sure you understand that code. This isn't the simplest t-sql ever and you will be the one supporting it at 3am when the phone rings. :D

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it but I will definitely have to write it again myself to understand it fully.